# lodash/fp transform not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I wanted to contribute a fix for this to the `lodash` repo but thought I should check that I'm not doing something wrong first...

When I use standard lodash in this example...

```
const _ = require('lodash');

run = () => {
  const mapping = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'world'
  };

  const object = {
    a: { value: true },
    b: { value: false }
  };

  // this is the original transform function that takes three arguments...
  // 1. the object to be transformed
  // 2. the transform function
  // 3. the accumulator object
  const transformed = _.transform(
    object,
    (a, v, k, o) => { a[mapping[k]] = _.get(v, 'value'); },
    {}
  );

  console.log(transformed);
};

run();
```

The output is `{ hello: true, world: false }` like I expected.

When logging a, v, k, and o on the above code the output is...

```
1 a: {}
1 v: { value: true }
1 k: a
1 o: { a: { value: true }, b: { value: false } }

2 a: { hello: true }
2 v: { value: false }
2 k: b
2 o: { a: { value: true }, b: { value: false } }
```

However, when I run (what I think is) the equivalent code using lodash/fp...

```
const _ = require('lodash/fp');

run = () => {
  const mapping = {
    a: 'hello',
    b: 'world'
  };

  const object = {
    a: { value: true },
    b: { value: false }
  };

  // this is the fp transform function that takes two arguments...
  // 1. the transform function
  // 2. the accumulator object
  // it then returns a function that takes one argument...
  // 1. the object to be transformed
  const transformed = _.transform(
    (a, v, k, o) => { a[mapping[k]] = _.get('value')(v); },
    {}
  )(object);

  console.log(transformed);
};

run();
```

The output is `{ undefined: false }`. This is because the parameters to the iterator do not seem to be correct. When I log a, v, k, and o I get the following output...

```
1 a: {}
1 v: { value: true }
1 k: undefined
1 o: undefined

2 a: { undefined: true }
2 v: { value: false }
2 k: undefined
2 o: undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not working as expected?

I have also added this as an issue on the repo but thought I'd add here as maybe I would get a faster response :D

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4381

Comment: Never used fp but just went to the Guide wiki and # of arguments is different  https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide  `Methods that cap iteratees to two arguments:
reduce, reduceRight, & transform`

Comment: @charlietfl yep, that's what I have done in my code. In the original code it takes three arguments, the object, the function and the accumulator. In the `fp` code it takes two arguments, the function and the accumulator. It then returns a function that takes the object as it's only argument.

Comment: what I am reading from it is iteratee is the the transform function...and it only has 2 arguments

Comment: @charlietfl oh... I see now... one sec, need to check this... Thanks :D

Comment: Can check arguments length easily by using regular function instead of arrow function and inspect arguments array

Comment: @charlietfl ok, with a regular function (if I give it 2 parameters... `a` and `v`) I can check `arguments` in the function and there are 4 arguments (`a`, `v`, `k`, `o` like I would expect)... UNLESS I actually put 4 arguments into the function signature and then there are only two arguments in `arguments`. It's odd... but I can get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const transform = _.transform.convert({ cap: false });
const transformed = transform(
  (a, v, k, o) => { a[mapping[k]] = _.get('value')(v); },
  {}
)(object);
```

[pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QejReq)

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's very odd but I can get it working.

When using `lodash/fp` the autocompletion of the `iteratee` shows the function signature like...

```
function(accumulator, currentValue) {}
```

So it will only accept two arguments (which is what is said in the documentation linked to by @charlietfl).

However, when I create the function like this...

```
function(a, v) {
  console.log(arguments.length);
}
```

It outputs `4`.

So I kept exploring...

```
function(a, v) {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  console.log(arguments[2]);
  console.log(arguments[3]);
}
```

This outputs...

```
1 a: {}
1 v: { value: true }
1 k: a
1 o: { a: { value: true }, b: { value: false } }

2 a: {}
2 v: { value: false }
2 k: b
2 o: { a: { value: true }, b: { value: false } }
```

Just like I wanted it to. So, even though the function is only declared with 2 arguments and only accepts 2 parameters, 4 arguments are actually passed into it.

So, when I update the code like this...

```
function(a, v) {
  const k = arguments[2];
  a[mapping[k]] = v.value;
}
```

This returns `{ hello: true, world: false }` which is what I was hoping to get in the first place.

I can get around it this way but don't understand why this is happening. So, because of that I'm going to stick with my current method of `mapKeys` followed by `mapValues` and TBH... I'll probably be looking at dropping `lodash` in the near future and writing my own functions to replace this functionality.